# CreateprocessAsUserA Using LogonUserA

Tags: c++, winapi

```
LPCSTR  lpszUsername = "admin user";
LPCSTR  lpszDomain =  "DESKTOP-H60GO83";
LPCSTR  lpszPassword = "password";
DWORD   dwLogonType = LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE;
DWORD   dwLogonProvider = LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40;
PHANDLE hToken;

LogonUserA(
    lpszUsername,
    lpszDomain,
    lpszPassword,
    dwLogonType,
    dwLogonProvider,
    hToken);
      
memset(&sui, 0, sizeof(sui));
  
sui.cb = sizeof(sui);
     
LPTSTR lpApplicationName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe ";
      
CreateProcessAsUserA(
    hToken,
    lpApplicationName,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &sui,
    &pi
);
```

That's my code. What am I doing wrong? Process exits immediately when the console loads.

I need this to add to my reverse shell.

I used `CreateProcess()` and it worked. I'm using `CreateProcessAsUserA()` to give my shell admin privileges.

Comment: sorry, it's unclear what you even try to do hjere, and the example you gave not only is horrendously misformatted and indented, it's also not free-standing enough so that we could compile it or even understand where it goes wrong. So, you'll need to debug this yourself a bit more or come up with a *minimal, verifiable example*.

Comment: @MarcusMüller I think you particularly do not understand what I'm trying to do here... I'm trying to create a process with the Current administrator token..

Comment: @MarcusMüller I'm not sure you read what I wrote or checked the code if not you would have known that LogonUserA gets the token I can use to give my process I'm trying to create administrative privileges. My only issue is that my process exists immediately it opens up. So I asked what I'm doing wrong , I'm not sure if you want me to post the complete code here but with the little you can see above I'm sure you'll be able to figure out something and help me out.. I respect and appreciate your comment.

Comment: @Marsha4Coding "*I'm not sure if you want me to post the complete code here*" - we expect you to post a [mcve] so others can reproduce the same problem you are experiencing. Which is WHAT, exactly? All you said is "*Process exits immediately when the console loads*", what does that even mean? WHICH process? Be more specific.

Comment: I have provided the code already.

Answer (score 0):

You are not using the `hToken` variable correctly.

You have declared an *uninitialized pointer* to a `HANDLE`, but are not pointing it at a valid `HANDLE`.  You are then passing that bad pointer to `LogonUserA()`, which is *undefined behavior*.  And then you are passing that bad pointer to `CreateProcessAsUserA()`, which doesn't even want a *pointer* to a `HANDLE` to begin with, it wants the actual `HANDLE` instead.

You are also not checking for errors from the API calls.

Try this instead:

```
LPCSTR  lpszUsername = "admin user";
LPCSTR  lpszDomain =  "DESKTOP-H60GO83";
LPCSTR  lpszPassword = "password";
DWORD   dwLogonType = LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE;
DWORD   dwLogonProvider = LOGON32_PROVIDER_WINNT40;
HANDLE hToken = NULL; // <-- no P !

if (!LogonUserA(
    lpszUsername,
    lpszDomain,
    lpszPassword,
    dwLogonType,
    dwLogonProvider,
    &hToken)) // <-- add & !
{
    // error handling...
}
      
STARTUPINFO sui;
memset(&sui, 0, sizeof(sui));
sui.cb = sizeof(sui);
     
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

LPTSTR lpApplicationName = "C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";
      
if (!CreateProcessAsUserA(
    hToken,
    lpApplicationName,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    TRUE,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    NULL,
    &sui,
    &pi
))
{
    // error handling ...
}

...

CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
```

Comment: I got the same error i got from mine..

Comment: And what error is that, exactly? You didn't say anything about an error. Exiting after launch is not an error.

Comment: My bad I meant to say process exit after launch...it's not an error.

Answer (score 0):

```
/*
author: @......MARSHA4CODING
*/
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>

using namespace std;

STARTUPINFO sui;
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

int main(){



LPCSTR  lpszUsername = "ADMIN";
LPCSTR  lpszDomain =  " DESKTOP- 
H60GO73";
LPCSTR  lpszPassword = "PASSWORD" ;
DWORD   dwLogonType = 
LOGON32_LOGON_INTERACTIVE;
DWORD   dwLogonProvider =  
LOGON32_PROVIDER_DEFAULT ;
HANDLE hToken = NULL; // <-- no P !

if (!LogonUserA(
lpszUsername,
lpszDomain,
lpszPassword,
dwLogonType,
dwLogonProvider,
&hToken)) // <-- add & !
{
DWORD rx2 =   GetLastError();
return rx2;
}
  
STARTUPINFO sui;
memset(&sui, 0, sizeof(sui));
sui.cb = sizeof(sui);
 
PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;

LPTSTR lpApplicationName = 
"C:\\Windows\\System32\\cmd.exe";

HANDLE phNewToken; // stores either the 
Primary or Impersonation token gotten 
from DuplicateTokenEx

//LPSECURITY_ATTRIBUTES        
lpTokenAttributes
//SECURITY_IMPERSONATION_LEVEL 
ImpersonationLevel
if(!DuplicateTokenEx(hToken,
0,lpTokenAttributes,
ImpersonationLevel,1,phNewToken)){
cout<<"Duplication Error";
}
  
if (!CreateProcessAsUserA(
hToken,
lpApplicationName,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
TRUE,
NULL,
NULL,
NULL,
&sui,
&pi
))
{
 DWORD rx2 =   GetLastError();
 return rx2;
 }



 CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
 CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);

 return 0; 


 }
```

I think the issue is with the
DuplicateTokenEx();
function because the token I'm supposed to get from the
LogonUserA();
Will be used to generate either a Primary or Impersonation Token with
DuplicateTokenEx(); function
So my challenge right now is with the
TokenAttributes and Impersonationlevel when using
DuplicateTokenEx(): function I don't know what to write there, Pardon my silly Questions.

Comment: Any idea of what goes into TokenAttributes and Impersonationlevel ??